# EF Core, navigation property HasMany / WithMany without join table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I have two tables:

Table `Cards` with the following Columns:

```
Id (Unique Index/Primary Key)
OracleId (Guid, NOT Unique)
CardName
CardText
SetName
...
```

Table `CardRulings`:

```
OracleId (Guid, Indexed, NOT Unique)
Source
Comment
```

I'm looking for a simple navigation property. `Card.Rulings` should have a collection (`ICollection<CardRuling>`) of associated CardRulings from the table. CardRulings is a keyless table and there are duplicate OracleId's in both the Cards and CardRulings table. This isn't quite a HasMany/WithMany as there is no key technically in either table, and there is no "unique" index that links the two tables together.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is. You have not asked any question. Please [edit] your question to include a question and if possible, add a [mcve]. Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: It is unclear indeed, also if You have many-to-many You need the table in between.

Comment: @Progman Not exactly sure how it's unclear. I described the tables, and I described exactly what I want accomplished. `var card = _dbContext.Cards.First(c => c.Id == myGuid);` `card.CardRulings` should be a list of card rulings. @Kronrad, there doesn't need to be a table in between, if I simply have many oracle ID's to many oracle ID's in the rulings table. Any card with oracle ID 123, should find the list of rulings from the cardrulings table where oracle ID is 123.

Comment: This seems simple and straightforward. It seems a normal relation, which you can achieve with fluent and attribute syntax, or probably even automatic mapping. Please show what you tried and explain where it failed. However, due to the ORM nature of EF, each object generated will have its own reference to the joined objects. I do want to state that I might be misunderstanding what you really want. You are using many words, but information is scattered all over them. Less=more: try to compact your question into a focused problem.  Maybe look at the help section for tips.

Comment: @Blue Please [edit] your question to include sample data with enough rows in both tables. It sounds like you have unique values in the `CardRulings.OracleId` column but it also sounds like you have multiple `CardRulings` rows with the same `CardRulings.OracleId` value. Providing the sample data might clear things up on the relationship between these tables. If necessary, adjust the numbers you use in your question for that specific sample data set. Do not pick a too small example data set, where the multiplicity isn't shown/visible.

Comment: @Progman Check updated question. The only unique index/primary key is on the Card table and that's Id.

Comment: @Blue Is it an option to have an intermediate table `Oracle`, which can be referenced by `Card` and have multiple `CardRulings`? So you have something like `Cards(Id, OracleId, [...])`, `Oracles(Id)` and `CardRulings(Id, OracleId, [...])`. That way your `Card` entity can reference one specific `Oracle` entity and that entity can have a normal navigation collection for the `CardRuling` entities. The query will look something like `dbContext.Cards.Include(it => it.Oracle.CardRulings)`.

Comment: I'd rather not involve another table if I don't have to @Progman.

Comment: The answer is simple: can't be done. EF only allows relationships that refer to a unique key. The so-called many-to-many with skip navigations consists of two 1:n associations under the covers and requires a junction table in the database. So, either add the junction table or fix it in code, as you did.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```cs
var cards = _dbContext.Cards.select(c=>new CardsDTO(){
                                          Id = c.Id,
                                          OracleId= c.OracleId,
                                          CardName = c.CardName,
                                          CardText = c.CardText, 
                                          SetName = c. SetName,
                                          CardRulings = new List<CardRulings>();
                                       });

var cardRuling = _dbContext.CardRulings.ToList();

foreach(var item in cards){
     item.CardRulings = cardRuling.Where(f=> f.OracleId = item.OracleId).ToList()
}
```

Comment: If I fetch 100 cards, that's going to run 101 queries on the db. This isn't exactly performant, and I'd rather just go a dictionary route instead using something similar to `cards.Select(c => c.OracleId).Contains(f.OracleId)` and using a dictionary to assign them to the associated cards. I wanted to do this via a navigational property.

Comment: @Blue no its run only one query, no meter how many card exists.

Comment: Yeah, this is about as "unperformant" as we can get. It will literally fetch the entire card ruling db, put it into a list, and the `Where()` is horrendous as well. You're better off making a lookup here.

Comment: Just want to say: I awarded you the bounty because I can't delete this question. For people reading this, DON'T use this answer, it's about the worst performance you can get, queries literally every row in the `cardRuling` database (Not filtering at all). At absolute worst, you should at least use a lookup for performant oracleId lookups, otherwise every `.Where()` statement occurs an `O(n)` vs `O(1)` penalty. Just awful.